# I would like someone to explain me how to find highest normal form of relation

Tags: database

For the relation below, determine the highest normal form the relation is in, the reason, and if necessary normalize the relation, and all resulting relations, through BCNF.  Use proper relational notation and include reference statements for any foreign keys.

```
Q1( a, b, c, d )
```

Functional Dependencies: a and b are candidate keys

a, b -> c, d

c -> d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left side of FD must be candidate key OR right side must be at least part of it in order to satisfy 3NF.
So, you have problem with c -> d because c is not candidate key and d is not part of it.